# How can I create 6 bins and count all values that fall in each bin?

Tags: r, correlation, bins

I have a few correlation matrices. I want to see how many values fall in 6 bins as follows; bin 1: 0 to 0.1, 0.1 to 0.2, 0.2 to 0.3, 0.3 to 0.4, 0.4 to 0.5 and 0.5 to 1.

My matrix: 
`dput(head(x3,n=1))
structure("1 0.0118056267220191 0.0698430295769578 0.147675160526577 -0.240526687986192 -0.240526687986192 NA -0.0864263397068391 0.0472030857452077 0.144075169217511 -0.169335298346717 -0.136657358184974 0.0997757565385112 0.0318247578607896 -0.121466138394709 0.0698430295769578 0.0372342961702855 0.162822402256459 0.0698430295769578 -0.228614978429606 -0.00325644804512918  -0.0864263397068391 0.128784183243357 0.0698430295769578 0.0772194756468332 -0.0850262968762965 -0.0850262968762965 -0.0850262968762965 -0.35016924446602 0.0440944056879946 -0.171996312074949 0.144075169217511 0.150114837624665 0.0698430295769578 0.0698430295769578 0.0772194756468332 -0.0238936680131698 -0.0900497873763463 0.0997757565385112 -0.0465278278289626 0.0117475463077051 0.0824568591955934 -0.0900497873763463 -0.0257843138721356 0.0723951333229052 -0.286356421265527 0.0698430295769578 0.119512195121951 0.027050089040023 -0.0753353976483616 0.123466199581199 -0.0864263397068391 0.0997757565385112 -0.0396206715348156 0.123466199581199 0.144075169217511 0.180333926933486  0.288860360879251 -0.286356421265527 -0.030022967524933 -0.100304414707211 0.128045554224423 0.292369332798234 0.0997757565385112 -0.0401597420067507 0.0698430295769578 0.0698430295769578 0.0341553188670066 0.0997757565385112 ", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))`

I currently do not have a working example. Not sure how to approach this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `?cut` or `?findInterval`.  Looks like your dput is a single string.  Use `scan` to get the individual elements.

Comment: Ok, will check those out. Thanks.

Comment: Try `xNew <- scan(text=x3, what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE);cut(xNew, breaks=c(-Inf,0,0.1,0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,1))`

Comment: Awesome, trying it now. Will let you know in a sec.

Comment: For the counting part, you'll need `table`, as in `table(cut(xNew, breaks=c(-Inf,0,0.1,0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,1)))`.

Comment: `-Inf` will add the negative numbers. It looks like you only want 0 or positive values. `vec <- scan(text=df);table(cut(vec, c(seq(0,.5, .1),1), include.lowest=T))`

Comment: Says invalid text argument. Should my text be my original file. I changed it to a matrix.

Comment: Yes, I only want the positive values.

Comment: I get this error: Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  invalid 'text' argument

Comment: @Nev Is it based on the `scan` step.  But your dput works fine with me.

Comment: Yes. I was using read.table to read in the correlation matrix. i'm trying scan as you suggested.

Comment: @Nev I think you can use the `read.table` to read the file, with `row.names=1`.  Then, `unlist(dat)` and apply `cut` on it.

Comment: Thank you for help. Each of these options worked!!!!

Comment: @Nev No problem.  I don't know why I didn't posted the comment as an answer :-)

Comment: Its ok. Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec <- scan(text=x3)
tbl <- table(cut(vec, c(seq(0,.5, .1),1), include.lowest=T))
dimnames(tbl)[[1]] <- gsub(",", "-", gsub("\\[|\\(|\\]", "", dimnames(tbl)[[1]]))
tbl

  0-0.1 0.1-0.2 0.2-0.3 0.3-0.4 0.4-0.5   0.5-1 
     26      12       2       0       0       1
```

I added an extra step to format the names using `dimnames` and `gsub`.

**Data**

```
x3 <- structure("1 0.0118056267220191 0.0698430295769578 0.147675160526577 -0.240526687986192 -0.240526687986192 NA -0.0864263397068391 0.0472030857452077 0.144075169217511 -0.169335298346717 -0.136657358184974 0.0997757565385112 0.0318247578607896 -0.121466138394709 0.0698430295769578 0.0372342961702855 0.162822402256459 0.0698430295769578 -0.228614978429606 -0.00325644804512918  -0.0864263397068391 0.128784183243357 0.0698430295769578 0.0772194756468332 -0.0850262968762965 -0.0850262968762965 -0.0850262968762965 -0.35016924446602 0.0440944056879946 -0.171996312074949 0.144075169217511 0.150114837624665 0.0698430295769578 0.0698430295769578 0.0772194756468332 -0.0238936680131698 -0.0900497873763463 0.0997757565385112 -0.0465278278289626 0.0117475463077051 0.0824568591955934 -0.0900497873763463 -0.0257843138721356 0.0723951333229052 -0.286356421265527 0.0698430295769578 0.119512195121951 0.027050089040023 -0.0753353976483616 0.123466199581199 -0.0864263397068391 0.0997757565385112 -0.0396206715348156 0.123466199581199 0.144075169217511 0.180333926933486  0.288860360879251 -0.286356421265527 -0.030022967524933 -0.100304414707211 0.128045554224423 0.292369332798234 0.0997757565385112 -0.0401597420067507 0.0698430295769578 0.0698430295769578 0.0341553188670066 0.0997757565385112 ", .Dim = c(1L, 
1L))
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks Pierre. Should I not use read.table? Just use scan on my original data?

Comment: If `x3` is the direct output of your data scan will work. But it's dependent on the specific data structure you're working with.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I think each of these options provided exactly what I was looking for. I will triple check and hope its consistent with other matrices. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Yes Pierre, I had to go back to the original. I had written it to a file so that was giving me the error. You are correct.